# Why wasn't Suigintou's Rosa Mystica received by Shinku in the second season?

Tags: rozen-maiden

In the first season, after Suigintou was defeated/destroyed by Shinku, Shinku never received Suigintou's Rosa Mystica.

In the second season, Suigintou was restored, and this time around, she finally lost her Rosa Mystica after being destroyed during the final Alice Game.

While Hina Ichigo also didn't lose her Rosa Mystica when she lost, it was revealed in the second season that it only happened because she agreed to be Shinku's servant. When the Alice Game started in earnest, her Rosa Mystica was then received by Shinku.

How come Shinku never received Suigintou's Rosa Mystica after her first defeat, when it's shown that all the other Rozen Maidens lost theirs after being destroyed (with the exception of Hina Ichigo)?

Comment: Half of second season (Traumend) and including the OVA (Overture) contains materials that are original. Not sure whether it explains the discrepancies, though. I think you should give manga a read for the actual storyline.